# download pdf from modal div with seleium and Python

Tags: selenium, pdf, modal-dialog, save

I'm using selenium with python to do a script witch it connect and go to the page and click to a button which open a modal and the print dialogbox, and in this modal their are another button to dowload but i can't click on it. The consol say : Unable to locate element: [id="download"].
I would like to download this file on pdf (and send it in email but it's another question).
Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you able to manually click on the download button but not with selenium?

Comment: Yes exactly, i don't know why

Comment: Are you able to right click on the download button and click "Inspect"?

Comment: Yes it's my last picture

Comment: If the download button is in an iframe you will need to switch to the iframe first. See this stackoverflow question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python